# Angularjs compiled template not updating markup data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm working on an Angular JS project where I have to send html template filled with a form content via ajax. The markup gets transformed into an array of elements that when appended or send via email work perfectly but the values inside the {{curly braces}} don't get updated.

js:

```
  function CheckoutOverviewController( $scope, $compile, $templateCache) {    
    $scope.value = 'value to be passed';
    var template = $templateCache.get('template.tpl.html');
    var element = $compile(template)($scope);
  }
```

As the template won't go to the DOM i've decided not to use a directive.
If you have any advice on how to proceed, i'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you need to use $eval to evaluate the expressions?

Comment: The thing is that I don't need to evaluate anything. I just need the values to get fetched upon compilation (or some other process if needed, obviously). Thanks anyway